# How to Filter data in HTML Table with 3 DropDowns

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I want to filter data in the html table based on 3 dropdown list values (standort, status and infrastructure). --> ddlStandort, ddlStatus, ddlInfrastruktur
My below code is not working, I don't know why.....

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ddlStandort,#ddlStatus,#ddlInfrastruktur").on("change", function () {
            var standort = $('#ddlStandort').find("option:selected").val();
            var status = $('#ddlStatus').find("option:selected").val();
            var infrastructure = $('#ddlInfrastruktur').find("option:selected").val();
            SearchData(standort, status, infrastructure)
        });
    });
    function SearchData(standort, status, infrastructure) {
        if (standort.toUpperCase() == 'All' && status.toUpperCase() == 'All' && infrastructure.toUpperCase() == 'All') {
            $('#table11 tbody tr').show();
        } else {
            $('#table11 tbody tr:has(td)').each(function () {
                var rowStandort = $.trim($(this).find('td:eq(9)').text());
                var rowStatus = $.trim($(this).find('td:eq(5)').text());
                var rowInfrastructure = $.trim($(this).find('td:eq(10)').text());
                if (standort.toUpperCase() != 'All' && status.toUpperCase() != 'All' && infrastructure.toUpperCase() != 'ALL') {
                    if (rowStandort.toUpperCase() == standort.toUpperCase() && rowStatus == status && rowInfrastructure == infrastructure) {
                        $(this).show();
                    } else {
                        $(this).hide();
                    }
                } else if ($(this).find('td:eq(9)').text() != '' || $(this).find('td:eq(5)').text() != '' || $(this).find('td:eq(10)').text() != '') {
                    if (standort != 'All') {
                        if (rowStandort.toUpperCase() == standort.toUpperCase()) {
                            $(this).show();
                        } else {
                            $(this).hide();
                        }
                    }
                    if (status != 'All') {
                        if (rowStatus == status) {
                            $(this).show();
                        }
                        else {
                            $(this).hide();
                        }
                    }
                    if (infrastructure != 'All') {
                        if (rowInfrastructure == infrastructure) {
                            $(this).show();
                        }
                        else {
                            $(this).hide();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

**HTML/PHP**

```
<?php
        require("db_conn.php");
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `dspia_ip_state` ORDER BY state_id";
        $all_states = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        ?>
            <select id="ddlStatus" name="ddlStatus"><br>
                <option value="All">Status</option>
                <?php
                while ($state = mysqli_fetch_array(
                        $all_states,MYSQLI_ASSOC)):;
            ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $state["state"];
                ?>">
                    <?php echo $state["state"];
                    ?>
                </option>
            <?php
                endwhile;
            ?>
            </select>
        <?php
        require("db_conn.php");
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `dspia_location` ORDER BY location_id";
        $all_location = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        ?>
            <select id="ddlStandort" name="ddlStandort">
                <option value="All">Standort</option>
                <?php
                while ($location = mysqli_fetch_array(
                        $all_location,MYSQLI_ASSOC)):;
            ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $location["location"];
                ?>">
                    <?php echo $location["location"];
                    ?>
                </option>
            <?php
                endwhile;
            ?>
            </select>
        <?php
        require("db_conn.php");
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `dspia_infrastructure` ORDER BY infrastructure_id";
        $all_infrastructure = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        ?>
            <select id="ddlInfrastruktur" name="ddlInfrastruktur">
                <option value="All">Infrastruktur</option>
                <?php
                while ($infrastructure = mysqli_fetch_array(
                        $all_infrastructure,MYSQLI_ASSOC)):;
            ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $infrastructure["infrastructure"];
                ?>">
                    <?php echo $infrastructure["infrastructure"];
                    ?>
                </option>
            <?php
                endwhile;
            ?>
            </select>
```

the table data is selected from a database

**Whole Code**

```
<body>
        <div class="row header">
                <a href="home.php"><img id="drv" src="img/neueip/logo_drv_berlin-brandenburg_web.jpg"></a>
                <div class= "header-text">
                    <h2>IP-Adressverwaltung</h2>
                </div>
                <div class= "header-line">
                    <h1>|</h1>
                </div>
            <div class="col-50 rechts">
            <?php
            if($_SESSION['is_admin'] =='1'){
                ?>
                <div class="verwaltung">
                    <button class="dropbtn"><b>Verwaltung</b></button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="home.php">IP-Adresse</a>
                    <a href="benutzer.php">Benutzer</a>
                    <a href="status.php">Status</a>
                    <a href="standort.php">Standort</a>
                    <a href="betriebssystem.php">Betriebssystem</a>
                    <a href="infrastruktur.php">Infrastruktur</a>
                </div>
                </div>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
                <a href="logout.php"><img src="img/home/logout.png" class="logout"></a>
                <div class= "user">
                    <h3>| Benutzer: <?php print_r($_SESSION['login_name']); ?> |</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--
            <div class="gesamtPapierkorb">
            <a href="home.php"><img src="img/home/gesamtPapierkorb.png"></a>
            </div>
            -->
        </div>
        <div class="reload">
            <a href="home.php"><img src="img/home/refresh.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="filtern">
        <?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `dspia_ip_state` ORDER BY state_id";
        $all_states = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        ?>
            <select id="ddlStatus" name="ddlStatus"><br>
                <option value="All">Status</option>
                <?php
                while ($state = mysqli_fetch_array(
                        $all_states,MYSQLI_ASSOC)):;
            ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $state["state"];
                ?>">
                    <?php echo $state["state"];
                    ?>
                </option>
            <?php
                endwhile;
            ?>
            </select>
        <?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `dspia_location` ORDER BY location_id";
        $all_location = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        ?>
            <select id="ddlStandort" name="ddlStandort">
                <option value="All">Standort</option>
                <?php
                while ($location = mysqli_fetch_array(
                        $all_location,MYSQLI_ASSOC)):;
            ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $location["location"];
                ?>">
                    <?php echo $location["location"];
                    ?>
                </option>
            <?php
                endwhile;
            ?>
            </select>
        <?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `dspia_infrastructure` ORDER BY infrastructure_id";
        $all_infrastructure = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        ?>
            <select id="ddlInfrastruktur" name="ddlInfrastruktur">
                <option value="All">Infrastruktur</option>
                <?php
                while ($infrastructure = mysqli_fetch_array(
                        $all_infrastructure,MYSQLI_ASSOC)):;
            ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $infrastructure["infrastructure"];
                ?>">
                    <?php echo $infrastructure["infrastructure"];
                    ?>
                </option>
            <?php
                endwhile;
            ?>
            </select>
        </div>
        
        <input type="text" id="suchleiste" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Suchen...">
        
        </div>
        <div class="IPbutton">
            <form action="newip.php"  method="post">
            <button class="IP" type="submit"><b>+  Neue IP-Adresse</b></button>
            </form>
        </div>
       
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    
    
    
    <div class="tabelle">
    <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
    <table id=table11>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th onclick="sortID()">ID</th>
            <th onclick="sortTable(1)">IP-Adresse ↕</th>
            <th onclick="sortTable(2)">Hostname ↕</th>
            <th onclick="sortTable(3)">MAC-Adresse ↕</th>
            <th onclick="sortTable(4)">PW_Neu ↕</th>
            <th onclick="sortTable(5)">Status ↕</th>
            <th onclick="sortTable(6)">Beschreibung ↕</th>
            <th onclick="sortTable(7)">Betriebssystem ↕</th>
            <th onclick="sortTable(8)">Admin ↕</th>
            <th onclick="sortTable(9)">Standort ↕</th>
            <th onclick="sortTable(10)">Infrastruktur ↕</th>
            <th onclick="sortTable(11)">Workorder ↕</th>
            <th onclick="sortTable(12)">Anmerkungen ↕</th>
        </tr>
        
<?php
if(isset($_GET["del"])){
    if(!empty($_GET["del"])){
        $main_id = $_GET["del"];
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM dspia_main WHERE main_id = '".$main_id."'");
        
        if($stmt->execute()){
            ?>
            <div class="alert">
            <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span> 
            <strong>
            <?php
            print "Die IP-Adresse wurde gelöscht.";
            ?>
            </strong> 
            </div>
            <?php
        }else{
            print $conn->error; 
        }
    }
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM v_dspia_main";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

while($dsatz = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    ?>
    <tbody id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <th><a href="editIP.php?id=<?php echo $dsatz["main_id"] ?>"><img src="img/home/stift.png" class="Stift" width="auto" height="30"></a><a href="home.php?del=<?php echo $dsatz["main_id"] ?>"onclick='return confirmSubmit()'><img src="img/home/mülleimer.png" class="Mülleimer" width="auto" height="33" class="Mülleimer"></th>
        <td><?php echo $dsatz["main_id"] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $dsatz["ip_v4"] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $dsatz["hostname"] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $dsatz["mac_address"] ?></td>
        <td><?php if($dsatz["pw_new"] == "1") {
            echo "Ja";
        }else if($dsatz["pw_new"] == "0"){
            echo "Nein";
        } ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $dsatz["state"] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $dsatz["description"] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $dsatz["op_system"] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $dsatz["operator"] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $dsatz["location"] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $dsatz["infrastructure"] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $dsatz["workorder"] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $dsatz["remarks"] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    <colgroup>
    <col width="5%">
    </colgroup>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Tables =
main_dspia (main table)
v_main_dspia (view to show the table on website)
dspia_ip_state (for the Dropdown state)
dspia_location (for the Dropdown location)
dspia_infrastructure (for the Dropdown infrastructure)

[Table with DropDown Filter and Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ikn4.png)

[dspia_infrastructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bC7VH.png)

[dspia_ip_state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NLrU.png)

[dspia_location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/darPU.png)

[dspia_op_system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZH4oY.png)

[dspia_user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQEy3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your Javascript code works fine. There is something wrong with your data in php/html.
Check the following example:

```
<select id="ddlStandort">
    <option value="All">All</option>
    <option value="TestValue1">TestValue1</option>
    <option value="TestValue2">TestValue2</option>
</select>

<br>

<select id="ddlStatus">
    <option value="All">All</option>
    <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
    <option value="Sent">Sent</option>
</select>

<br>

<select id="ddlInfrastruktur">
    <option value="All">All</option>
    <option value="Cars">Cars</option>
    <option value="Motorcycles">Motorcycles</option>
</select>

<br>

<table id="table11">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Entry Code</th>
            <th>--------</th>
            <th>--------</th>
            <th>--------</th>
            <th>--------</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>--------</th>
            <th>--------</th>
            <th>--------</th>
            <th>Standort</th>
            <th>Infrastruktur</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Pending</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>TestValue1</td>
            <td>Cars</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Sent</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>TestValue2</td>
            <td>Motorcycles</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ddlStandort,#ddlStatus,#ddlInfrastruktur").on("change", function () {
            var standort = $('#ddlStandort').find("option:selected").val();
            var status = $('#ddlStatus').find("option:selected").val();
            var infrastructure = $('#ddlInfrastruktur').find("option:selected").val();
            SearchData(standort, status, infrastructure)
        });
    });
    function SearchData(standort, status, infrastructure) {
        if (standort.toUpperCase() == 'All' && status.toUpperCase() == 'All' && infrastructure.toUpperCase() == 'All') {
            $('#table11 tbody tr').show();
        } else {
            $('#table11 tbody tr:has(td)').each(function () {
                var rowStandort = $.trim($(this).find('td:eq(9)').text());
                var rowStatus = $.trim($(this).find('td:eq(5)').text());
                var rowInfrastructure = $.trim($(this).find('td:eq(10)').text());
                if (standort.toUpperCase() != 'All' && status.toUpperCase() != 'All' && infrastructure.toUpperCase() != 'ALL') {
                    if (rowStandort.toUpperCase() == standort.toUpperCase() && rowStatus == status && rowInfrastructure == infrastructure) {
                        $(this).show();
                    } else {
                        $(this).hide();
                    }
                } else if ($(this).find('td:eq(9)').text() != '' || $(this).find('td:eq(5)').text() != '' || $(this).find('td:eq(10)').text() != '') {
                    if (standort != 'All') {
                        if (rowStandort.toUpperCase() == standort.toUpperCase()) {
                            $(this).show();
                        } else {
                            $(this).hide();
                        }
                    }
                    if (status != 'All') {
                        if (rowStatus == status) {
                            $(this).show();
                        }
                        else {
                            $(this).hide();
                        }
                    }
                    if (infrastructure != 'All') {
                        if (rowInfrastructure == infrastructure) {
                            $(this).show();
                        }
                        else {
                            $(this).hide();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The values of the DropDowns are from another table, not the main table. I dont know what to change.

Comment: @AminCoD can you paste the schema of the tables that you are using in your question?

Comment: I posted my code in my question.

Comment: @AminCoD It would be also helpful, if you posted the fields(columns) of the following tables: 1) dspia_ip_state   2) dspia_location  3) dspia_infrastructure.

Comment: I posted all tables in the question

Answer (score 0):

First, is not needed to include the db.connection file each time you execute a query, it's suficient to add it at the top file and to prevent duplicate db connection.
i recommend this syntax require_once("db_conn.php");

for your issue it's possible to do it in 2 ways:

**method 01**
add a filter form with get method and use the $_GET request in your php code

**Filter Form**

```
<form method="get">
<select name="filter-1" onchange="this.form.submit()">
<option value="f1-v1">F1V1</option>
<option value="f1-v2">F1V2</option>
<option value="f1-v3">F1V3</option>
</select>
<select name="filter-2" onchange="this.form.submit()">
<option value="f2-v1">F2V1</option>
<option value="f2-v2">F2V2</option>
<option value="f2-v3">F2V3</option>
</select>
<select name="filter-3" onchange="this.form.submit()">
<option value="f3-v1">F3V1</option>
<option value="f3-v2">F3V2</option>
<option value="f3-v3">F3V3</option>
</select>
```

this mean when one of the selectbox changes the form will be submitted and the url will be changed
https://exemple.com/page.php?filer-1=value&filer-2=value&filter-3=value

**PHP Code**

```
<?php 
require_once("db_conn.php");
if(isset($_GET['filter-1']) && isset($_GET['filter-2']) && isset($_GET['filter-3']) ) {
$fetchData = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 = '".$_GET['filter-1']."' && col2 = '".$_GET['filter-2']."' && col3 = '".$_GET['filter-3']."' "); 
}
else {
$fetchData = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM table ");
}
echo '<table>';
foreach($fetchData as $row) {
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>$row['col1']</td>'; //Filter 1 Value
echo '<td>$row['col2']</td>'; //Filter 2 Value
echo '<td>$row['col3']</td>'; //Filter 3 Value
echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

This is a simple example

**Methode 02**
use jquery + ajax to update the table data on filter form select change

I hope that this will help you to solve your problem or at least give you an idea on how to solve it

Good luck